# Solve CDFs from PDFs

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I am familiar with solving CDFs from PDFs from simple functions such as
$$f(x)\begin{cases}0.5 & 0\le x <1\\0, & otherwise\end{cases}$$

However, how are you to calculate the CDF from a PDF if were something along the lines of
$$f(x)\begin{cases}0 & -1\le x <-1\\B, & otherwise\end{cases}$$

with B being some value like $$\frac{1}{3x}$$ or something along those lines. I do not think that would actually work as a problem, but I am just wondering how to approach a question like this compared to the standard questions.

Answer (score 1):

For sufficiently nice PDFs (which probably includes all you will ever see), you can just use
$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)\;dt$$

Here, $F_X$ is the CDF and $f_X$ is the PDF for the random variable $X$.

If $f_X$ is defined piecewise, then you can break up the integral into intgrals over the various pieces. For example, if (where $a<b<c<d$)

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
A(x), & a < x < b\\
B(x), & c < x < d\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

then
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x\leq a\\
\int_a^xA(t)\;dt, & a<x\leq b\\
\int_a^bA(t)\;dt, & b<x\leq c\\
\int_a^bA(t)\;dt + \int_c^xB(t)\;dt, & c<x\leq d\\
\int_a^bA(t)\;dt + \int_c^dB(t)\;dt, & x>d\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am still confused on how to answer these questions if it were something like $$f(x)\begin{cases}0 & -1\le x <-1\\1/3x, & otherwise\end{cases}$$     though. This is because it is 0 if -1<x<1, and 1/3x otherwise, rather than the structure you mentioned. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, it is hard to explain.

Comment: In such a case, your cdf will be more and more increasing till reaching $x=-1$, then have a flat part on $[-1,1]$, then resume its increasing but less and less.

Answer (score 0):

If the pdf is 0 for x between -1 and 1 and f(x)  for other then the cdf is $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(x)dx+ \int_1^\infty f(x)dx$.

Comment: Okay, I kind of understand now. For other PDF/CDF problems, such as the first example in my question, I usually express the answer along the lines of $$CDF(x)\begin{cases}0, & x<0\\x^2, & 0\le x \le1\\1, & x>1\end{cases}\\$$. In this case, would $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(x)dx+ \int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ be the correct way to express it? After substituting f(x) of course.

Comment: Also, would this always result in 0? I used f(x) as 1/x^4 and the result was 0.